# AWS lambda module not found error when debugging locally using SAM cli and AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

I am trying to debug lambda function locally using SAM cli and AWS CDK. So I am getting error function module not found any idea why so? I have taken this project from github https://github.com/mavi888/cdk-serverless-get-started

function.js:

```
exports.handler = async function (event) {
  console.log("request:", JSON.stringify(event));

  // return response back to upstream caller
  return sendRes(200, "HELLLOOO");
};

const sendRes = (status, body) => {
  var response = {
    statusCode: status,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/html",
    },
    body: body,
  };
  return response;
};
```

Inside lib folder

```
// lambda function
    const dynamoLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "DynamoLambdaHandler", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      code: lambda.Code.asset("functions"),
      handler: "function.handler",
      environment: {
        HELLO_TABLE_NAME: table.tableName,
      },
    });
```

I am using `cdk synth > template.yaml` command which generates cloud formation template.yaml file. Now I find function name with logicalID eg: myFunction12345678 and then trying to debug it locally using this command `sam local invoke myFunction12345678`  in my case it is DynamoLambdaHandler function. I get function module not found error. Any idea what I am missing?

Code is available on github: https://github.com/mavi888/cdk-serverless-get-started

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `sam` runs a Docker container with a Volume mount from the current directory. So, it's not finding the Lambda code because the path to the code from your CloudFormation template that CDK creates does not include the `cdk.out` directory in which `cdk` creates the assets.

You have two options:

1. Run your `sam` command with a defined volume mount `sam local invoke -v cdk.out`
2. Run the command from within the `cdk.out` directory and pass the JSON template as an argument since `cdk` writes a JSON template: `sam local invoke -t <StackNameTemplate.json>`

I'd recommend the latter because you're working within the framework that CDK creates and not creating additional files.

Comment: But why does `sam local invoke myLanbdaFunction` is not working? I was referring this https://tlakomy.com/run-cdk-lambda-function-locally I am geenrating template.yaml file and then invoking the function that should work right?

Comment: There are a few reasons: (1)  `myFunction` is not the name of the resource in the CloudFormation template (2) for the reason that I provided in my answer -- it should not work. CDK and SAM are two separate projects that are maintained by separate teams within AWS. The fact that you _can_ make them work together does not mean that it should be expected.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error while using the second option. `"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'chrome-aws-lambda'..."`